# Querying the time on a DateTime field (MongoDB)

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoid

I have an Employee object with a DateTime field

```
{ 
  :_id => BSON::ObjectId('839273974937702'),
  :name => 'John Doe',
  :start_date => 2020-01-02 14:00:00 UTC,
}
```

If I want to query all the Employees who started at `14:00`, how would I do that? I'm using MongoDB to store our data.

This is what I did

```
employees = Employee.all.entries
employees.select { |employee| employee.start_date.strftime("%H:%M") == "14:00" }
```

Was wondering if there's a quicker and better way

Comment: If the `start_date` is a Date type then, a combination of [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) and [`$hour`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) can work like this: `db.employee.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $hour: '$start_date',
      },
      12
    ]
  }
})`. I'm sorry this snippet is javascriptish, I'm not a ruby person but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @OTZ Got it! Thank you!